# How to share something into a Reminders list?

Tags: iphone, ios, sharing, reminders

Suppose you are viewing a webpage and need to set a reminder to do something with this page. How might you go about doing this given that 'reminders' does not appear to be in the Share list in iOS 8.1.3?

Answer (score 1):

#### You can't, yet.

You need to create the reminder manually and copy-paste the URL into the notes if you need it.